# Angular passing data through router-outlet

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to pass data between parent and child components (so that I don't have to use the same service multiple times)? Files are shown below.

So I'm getting an adventure in my `adventure.component.ts`, and would like to still data from it in my `adventure-detail.component`. I know I can get the adventure again using my service, but is there a way to pass the adventure through the router-outlet?

**adventure.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { AdventureService } from './../adventure.service';
import { Adventure } from './../adventure';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="adventure">
      <h2>{{adventure.name}}</h2>
    </div>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})

export class AdventureComponent implements OnInit {
  adventure: Adventure;

  constructor(
    private adventureService: AdventureService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      let id = +params['id'];
      this.adventureService.getAdventure(id)
        .then(adventure => this.adventure = adventure);
    });
  }
}
```

**adventure-detail.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  template:  `
    <span>{{adventure.description}}</span>
  `
})

export class AdventureDetailComponent {

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  start(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['./', 'page', 1], { relativeTo: this.route })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Service:

```
import {Injectable, EventEmitter} from "@angular/core";    

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
onGetData: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

getData() {
  this.http.post(...params).map(res => {
    this.onGetData.emit(res.json());
  })
}
```

## Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';    
import {DataService} from "../services/data.service";       

@Component()
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private DataService:DataService) {
    this.DataService.onGetData.subscribe(res => {
      (from service on .emit() )
    })
  }

  //To send data to all subscribers from current component
  sendData() {
    this.DataService.onGetData.emit(--NEW DATA--);
  }
}
```